# Нужна ли точка в подписи к фото?

Tags: пунктуация

Ув. филологи, нужна ли точка в подписи к фото(та, что в конце предложения)?

Мэрилин Монро. Она же Норма Джин Бейкер**.**

Answer (score 1):

В конце не нужна.
    Просмотрела разные фото, точек не заметила.
    Нашла следующее:  [ССЫЛКА](http://www.az-print.com/index.shtml?FAQ&HelpBook/h021).

"`**21.2.2. Знак препинания в конце подписи**

Точки не ставят, за исключением случаев, когда подпись представляет собой цитату из иллюстрируемого художественного произведения (законченную фразу-цитату завершают точкой)."

На географических картах тоже мало точек. Только в конце сокращений.

Comment: Точка вас и подвела. В ссылке.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо Бегемотусу за внимательность и Марк Изу за внесенные изменения)

Comment: Это обычная история, уже многие на это напарывались.
Внимательность ни при чем. Я ткнул - а мне облом.

Answer (score 1):

У меня есть сомнения в авторитетности надюшкиного источника. 
В правилах на этот счет нет каких-то специальных оговорок, поэтому желание не ставить точку мне непонятно, особенно если подпись - законченное  предложение, а не просто фамилия того, кто на фотке.
Впрочем, не буду настаивать. Это уже какие-то издательско-полиграфические заморочки, не обычные правила пунктуации...

Comment: Если,  подпись  является  предложением  точка  нужна. Даже  если  это  и  не  цитата.  А  если  имя  собственное, то  и  так  и  так  встречается.  Может  способ  размещения  фотографии  имеет  какое-то  влияние,  если  специальных  оговорок  в  правилах  нет.