# Требуется ли точка в конце всплывающей подсказки?

Tags: пунктуация

во многих компьютерных интерфейсах (графические программы, веб-интерфейсы сайтов и т.п.) существуют всплывающие подсказки — при наведении [указателя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D1%8C) на какой-то элемент интерфейса рядом с указателем появляется надпись с дополнительной информацией об этом элементе (например, наведите указатель на слово «пунктуация» ниже текста вопроса).

следует ли при оформлении этой надписи, в частности, касательно конечного знака препинания, использовать тот же подход, что и, например, при оформлении заголовков:

> В современной русской печати в конце заголовка употребление точки не принято. Это положение узаконено специальными пособиями и справочниками для корректоров и редакторов; сошлемся хотя бы на последний такой по времени: «Точку в рубрике (заголовке. – Б. Ш.), вынесенной в отдельную строку, опускают, за исключением изданий для начинающих читать детей (напр., в букваре), чтобы не мешать закреплению стереотипа, в конце предложения надо ставить точку... Остальные [написано рукой автора: конечные] знаки препинания (многоточие, восклицательный, вопросительный знаки) сохраняют» (Справочная книга редактора и корректора. Составление и общая редакция А. Э. Мильчина. Изд. 2-е, М.: Книга, 1985. С. 24).
>   [Справочно-информационный портал ГРАМОТА.РУ](http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/rr/28_563)

или, например, подписей к иллюстрациям:

> 21.2.2. Знак препинания в конце подписи
>   Точки не ставят, за исключением случаев, когда подпись представляет собой цитату из иллюстрируемого художественного произведения (законченную фразу-цитату завершают точкой).
>   [Справочная книга редактора и корректора](http://www.az-print.com/FAQ/HelpBook/h021.shtml)

---

связанные вопросы:

- [Нужна ли точка в подписи к фото?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/24909/176866)
- [Знаки препинания в конце заголовков](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/417768/176866)

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что [причина возникновения данного вопроса](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35020627#35020627) затрагивает предложение, [отображаемое при наведении мыши на метку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xh0i.png).

Comment: Решил уточнить, является ли вопрос онтопиком. Тема на мете: http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/q/182/182097

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52619/discussion-on-question-by-alexander-barakin------).

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что здесь ещё нет правила. Но я бы провёл параллель между комментариями в обычной бумажной книге, примечаниями и всплывающими подсказками. Функционально они нацелены на одно и то же. Следовательно, точку необходимо ставить.

Answer (score 0):

Всплывающая подсказка - не заголовок и не подпись. Смело ставьте точку!